# Why can the odom frame drift?

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), "The pose of a mobile platform in the odom frame can drift over time".  I am trying understand what that means.  In what situations would the frame "drift"?  And "drift" relative to what?  The base_link?  How would the the odom frame drift relative to the base link if the robot is responsible for publishing the base_link->odom transform based on it's notion of odometry in the first place?

REP 105 also states/requires, "the pose of a robot in the odom frame is guaranteed to be continuous".

Does this mean I can't use an INDEX pulse on my wheel encoders to reset the axel angle to zero on each wheel rotation, since that might lead to a discontinuity?  Or does it imply a requirement that I must filter my odometry estimates to eliminate such discontinuities.

Hmmm... maybe this starts to make sense.  If I'm required (by REP 105) to eliminate any discontinuities, I can see where that might lead to "drift"...maybe.

Anyways, I'm confused, and would appreciate any enlightenment folks would care to give me on this topic.

--wpd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188882/why-can-the-odom-frame-drift?/) by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

As I understand, the *drift* mentioned on [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) refers to the fact that the difference between the pose of the robot on the real world and the estimated pose of the robot by the odometry (lets call this *odometry error*) will grow over time due the well-known problems of odometry calculation. For example:

- Small difference between the nominal and actual wheel diameter -> will cause the *odometry error* to grow over time
- Small difference between the nominal and actual tread -> will cause the *odometry error* to grow over time
- Wheel slipping -> will cause the *odometry error* to grow over time
- No matter what you do -> the *odometry error* will grow over time

Regarding the *continuity* of the odom frame, yes, you should avoid *big jumps*. The values on the odom frame should be continuous, and any compensation for the *odometry error* (*drift*) should be made on the *map* frame:

```
In a typical setup, a localization component constantly re-computes the robot pose in the map frame based on sensor observations, therefore eliminating drift, but causing discrete jumps when new sensor information arrives.
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on 2014-08-04**:
Ahhh, that makes sense.  Thank you.